# React-bootstrap: `NavBar` that has `Nav` with `fill` flag is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

As a title says, I want my `NavBar` to extend the full available width, so I add a `fill` flag to `Nav` in `NavBar` component.

```
  <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav fill className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/news">News</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/ship-schedule">Ship Schedule</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/media-sponsor">Media Sponsor</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/contacts">Contacts</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

But it isn't working, the `Nav.Link` components are still left aligned.

[image]

How can I make those `Nav.Link` components fill the width of the `Nav.Bar` component.

Comment: Could you please provide an online demo? Cause it's kind of hard to reproduce what you have met. And I think it may be a great help for others, too.

Comment: @keikai I have found the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Bootstrap API, to solve this problem, I have to add two css classes to `Nav` component.

```
...
<Nav className="w-100 nav-justified">
...
```

Remove `mr-auto` class, add two classes `w-100` and `nav-justified`. Then for each `Nav.Link` component, wrap it into a `Nav.Item` component, like this:

```
...
<Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
...
```